# php/ajax uploader bar?getting data for upload bar

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload

I am creating an upload interface to upload files in php.

Files are uploading fine.

But I want to give the user some feedback as how much time will it take to upload, how much of the uploading has been done etc..

I have found online code which gives ajax plugin to do what I want.

BUT my question is more fundamental, WHERE do I get the data in php that tells me how much of the file is received? what is the connection speed(connection speed and file size can be used to get time left) and other information needed?

can i get the data form php or am i looking at the wrong place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is in the documentation:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php

Answer (score 0):

> WHERE do i get the data in php that tells me how much of the file is received

You don't. Uploading is handled by the webserver. When the upload is complete your PHP script will run and it gets a reference to the temp file(s) created by your webserver.

<s>I think there are plugins or mods that do allow you to monitor theses processes</s>. There is [session.uploader-progress.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php)

but **there is a much easier solution**!

---

Use the JS `FileReader` API to slice the file into small chunks (like 5mb) then you can already make a pretty good loading bar. Additionally you can monitor the progress of `XMLHTTPRequest`s to see how many bytes have been sent. This should get you a pretty spot on progress indicator.

This also alleviates common problems with exceeding max_upload_size.

An actual code solution is quite involved so I will refrain from posting one. You should be able to find samples or tutorials.